# Unable Into "Step Over" Into Code In V/Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In V/Studio, I Have Tried:

1. Going To Tools >> Options >> Checking & Unchecking The Option: "Step Over Properties And Operators" >> Outcome: Error Still Persists And Issue Not Fixed
2. Restarting V/Studio 2019 >> Outcome: Error Still Persists And Issue Not Fixed
3. Shutdown All & Any 3rd Party Applications >> Outcome: Error Still Persists And Issue Not Fixed
4. The Physical "F10" Button On The Keybaord Does Not Work. But The "Step Over" / "Step Into" Buttons Work & I Have Been Using Them Successfully Up Until Now.

Your Help Is Highly Appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please check if you run app in Debug build. In Release you will have issues with controlling of the code flow.

Comment: The app is in "Debug build / mode". The app is not in the release build yet. It is on a stand alone environement im Visual Studio (on my PC alone).

Thanks.